# What is syntax to return member function pointer without typedef?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, typedef, return-type

This is a C++03 question.

In the following code, `class Foo` implements `operator[]` that returns a pointer to a member function. The code currently does this by returning a reference to a `TFunc`, which is `typedef`ed to a member function.

I'd like to learn: what would be the syntax of the `operator[]` definition without using `typedef`? You can see I flailed around a bit, without success, trying. My first thought was that `typedef` worked like a macro, i.e. that a simple string substitution should work - but apparently not. All the other variations I tried didn't work either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  typedef void (T::*TFunc)( const std::string&, const std::string& );
  typedef std::map< std::string, TFunc > FooMap;
  operator FooMap&()
  {
    return member_;
  }

  //void (T::*)( const std::string&, const std::string& ) operator []( const std::string& str )
  //void (T::*&)( const std::string&, const std::string& ) operator []( const std::string& str )
  //void (T::*)&( const std::string&, const std::string& ) operator []( const std::string& str )
  //void (T::*)( const std::string&, const std::string& )& operator []( const std::string& str )
  TFunc& operator []( const std::string& str )
  {
    return member_[ str ];
  }

private:
  FooMap member_;
};

class Bar
{
public:
  void func()
  {
    fb_["a"] = &Bar::abc;
  }

  void callFunc( const std::string& str, const std::string arg1,
                 const std::string& arg2 )
  {
    (this->*fb_[ str ])( arg1, arg2 );
  }

  void abc( const std::string& key, const std::string& val )
  {
    std::cout << key << ": " << val << std::endl;
  }

private:
  Foo<Bar> fb_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Bar b;
  b.func();
  b.callFunc( "a", "hello", "world" );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ugly syntax would be:

```
void (T::*&operator [](const std::string& str))(const std::string&, const std::string&);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/169513f57d8a1dd6)

Comment: Eek. It might've been years before I stumbled on that particular permutation. Thank you.

Comment: `using`/`typedef` is simpler/clearer. (Hopefully, you use a `std::map` and not a C-array of pointer on member ;-) )

Comment: "using/typedef is simpler/clearer." - Agreed, but I sometimes I just get this urge to see how things work under the hood. Thanks again for enlightening. (And yes: I use a `std::map` and not a C-style array. :) )

Answer (score 3):

In C++ 14 or later, you can use

```
decltype(auto)
```

as the return type

You might also consider using `std:: function` instead of what you currently have as the map's value type.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I forgot to note, though: I'm limited to C++03. I'll update the question for future readers.

Comment: @StoneThrow I see, sorry to hear that and thanks for clarifying